# Using Git to maintain two different versions of a LaTeX document

Tags: git, latex

My friend and I are both working on some math problems, and I'm typing up their solutions in Latex. However, there are some sections in the document meant for my personal use, and I don't need my friend to see those. Is there a way to have Git maintain two versions of that document, one version with my personal comments and the other without (the one I'm going to share)?

Comment: Sure! By using `branches`.

Comment: Thanks a lot! Git already showing its power (I'm a beginner :p)

Comment: Being a beginner, I'm a bit stuck in the process - I created a branch `discussions` where I went and removed the personal comments; then I added a new solution to the file. I now want the `master` branch to reflect the edits I made in the `discussion` branch. How do I do this?

Comment: @DGhosh you can go and check how [merging](https://git-scm.com/docs/git-merge) works.

Comment: @DGhosh, just switch to master branch back `git checkout master`, and then merge `disucssions` into `master`: `git merge discussions`

Comment: Just what I needed - I had to resolve a conflict, and now it's done.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create a new branch (call it `discussion`)and remove the parts of the text you need to remove. In order to update both the `master` branch and `discussion` branch with anything new , make the necessary edits to the `discussion` branch, and then use merging (resolve conflicts if necessary) to make the `master` branch reflect those edits.